# how to parse CSV to JSON from 2 CSV Files in Groovy

Tags: csv, groovy

Please help with parse CSV to JSON from 2 CSV Files in groovy
For example :
CSV1:

testKey,status

Name001,PASS

Name002,PASS

Name003,FAIL

CSV2:

Kt,Pd

PT-01,Name001

PT-02,Name002

PT-03,Name003

PT-04,Name004

I want to input in "testlist" data from CSV2.val[1..-1],CSV1.val[1..-1]

Result should be like :

```
  {
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info": {
        "user": "admin"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "TestKey": "PT-01",
            "status": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "TestKey": "PT-02",
            "status": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "TestKey": "PT-03",
            "status": "FAIL"
        }
    ]
```

code without this modification (from only 1 csv):

```
import groovy.json.*

def kindaFile = '''
TestKey;Finished;user;status
Name001;PASS;
Name002;PASS;
'''.trim()

def keys
def testList = []
//parse CSV
kindaFile.splitEachLine( /;/ ){ parts ->
  if( !keys )
    keys = parts
  else{
    def test = [:]
    parts.eachWithIndex{ val, ix -> test[ keys[ ix ] ] = val }
    testList << test
  }
}

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def root = builder {
  testExecutionKey 'DEMO-303'
  info user: 'admin'
  tests testList
}

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(root))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample JSON doesn't match the CSV definition. It looks lile you're using fields `[1..-1]` from CSV 1, as you stated, but fields `[0..-2]` from CSV 2. As you only have 2 fields in each CSV that's the equivalent of `csv1[1]` and `csv2[0]`. The example below uses `[0..-2]`. Note that if you always have exactly two fields in your input files then the following code could be simplified a little. I've given a more generic solution that can cope with more fields.

### Load both CSV files into lists

```
File csv1 = new File( 'one.csv')
File csv2 = new File( 'two.csv')

def lines1 = csv1.readLines()
def lines2 = csv2.readLines()

assert lines1.size() <= lines2.size()
```

Note the assert. That's there as I noticed you have 4 tests in CSV2 but only 3 in CSV1. To allow the code to work with your sample data, it iterates through through CSV1 and adds the matching data from CSV2.

#### Get the field names

```
fieldSep = /,[ ]*/

def fieldNames1 = lines1[0].split( fieldSep )
def fieldNames2 = lines1[0].split( fieldSep )
```

### Build the testList collection

```
def testList = []

lines1[1..-1].eachWithIndex { csv1Line, lineNo ->
  def mappedLine = [:]

  def fieldsCsv1 = csv1Line.split( fieldSep )
  fieldsCsv1[1..-1].eachWithIndex { value, fldNo -> 
    String name = fieldNames1[ fldNo + 1 ]
    mappedLine[ name ] = value
  }

  def fieldsCsv2 = lines2[lineNo + 1].split( fieldSep )
  fieldsCsv2[0..-2].eachWithIndex { value, fldNo -> 
    String name = fieldNames2[ fldNo ]
    mappedLine[ name ] = value
  }

  testList << mappedLine
}
```

### Parsing

You can now parse the list of maps with your existing code. I've made a change to the way the JSON string is displayed though.

```
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def root = builder {
  testExecutionKey 'DEMO-303'
  info user: 'admin'
  tests testList
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

### JSON Output

Running the above code, using your CSV1 and CSV 2 data, gives the JSON that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

for CSV1:

testKey,status

Name001,PASS

Name002,PASS

Name003,FAIL

and CSV2:

Kt,Pd
PT-01,Name007

PT-02,Name001

PT-03,Name003

PT-05,Name002

PT-06,Name004

PT-07,Name006

result is:

```
{
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info": {
        "user": "admin"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "status": "PASS",
            "testKey": "PT-01"
        },
        {
            "status": "PASS",
            "testKey": "PT-02"
        },
        {
            "status": "FAIL",
            "testKey": "PT-03"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I need exactly the same values for testKey (testKey from CSV1=Kt from CSV2)

```
{
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info": {
        "user": "admin"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "testKey": "PT-02",
             "status": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "testKey": "PT-05",
             "status": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "testKey": "PT-03",
             "status": "FAIL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: maybe in groovy is there a  similar function like in excel (VLOOKUP)  ?